# Can ICP4D (IBM Cloud Pak for Data) also be used as Data Quality tool?

Tags: cloud, websphere, data-quality, cloud-pak-for-data

Can ICP4D (IBM Cloud Pak for Data) also be used as DQ(Data Quality) tool ? I know it is primarily not meant for DQ but does it have capability to address few DQ dimensions/areas ?